# Is it possible to see all followers of a Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, followers

When I try to see all the followers of my Facebook account, after a few at the top which are randomly ordered, the rest is seen ordered alphabetically, and when I reach half of the usernames starting with "B", I can't browse / scrolldown the list anymore and the list ends there. Is it possible to see all followers of a Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Facebook for every data they collect about you.
You'll probably find in this file the data you're looking for.

> [image]
>   [Link](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992?helpref=hc_global_nav)